# Drilling Down Power Bi Matrix Table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

Is there anyway i can disable "Go to the Next level in the hierarchy (Button)"  but i want second Button to keep working.

[image: Power Bi Matrix Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this feature is not possible in PowerBI (Hopefully it will be in the future). In the meantime, you can try to hide this button by placing white rectangle shape in front of it...so user will not see nor be able to click it...